# Parsing huge xml files native vs javascript

Tags: javascript, android, xml-parsing, native

I need to parse big xml data from the servers. Which would be better on a mobile device:

1. Parsing it using xmlpullparser/sax.
2. Javascript based parsing.

Any performance numbers? Any suggestions of using renderscript (incase of android) here?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use SaxParser because it is good for large files through net

Comment: I knew that saxparsers are efficient for large data ,but what is preferrable doing it inside webkit or in javacode or use renderscript ?

Comment: first if you are satisfied accept the answers .i think it is preferrable to do it in javacode.

Comment: I am looking for detailed answers .Can you tell me why not in javascript ?